# Reading home files permission: Policy constraint violation

Tags: linux, debian, selinux

I want to confine a certain user to be able to bind a node.js server to a certain port. That bit is working.

What isn't working is allowing said user to access his own files.

audit2allow is telling me this:

```
#============= user_t ==============
#!!!! This avc is a constraint violation.  You will need to add an attribute to either the source or target type to make it work.
#Constraint rule: 
allow user_t user_home_t:dir { write remove_name add_name };
#!!!! This avc is a constraint violation.  You will need to add an attribute to either the source or target type to make it work.
#Constraint rule: 
allow user_t user_home_t:file { read write execute open };
```

I have no idea what attribute I could add to make it more clear my user should be able to access its own files.

Here's the audit.log entry

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1396865445.876:184): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=20389 comm="node" name="hawkejs-client-side.js" dev=md2 ino=92144931 scontext=sandbox_u:user_r:user_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=file
```

audit2why is giving me this:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1396865445.876:184): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=20389 comm="node" name="hawkejs-client-side.js" dev=md2 ino=92144931 scontext=sandbox_u:user_r:user_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=file

    Was caused by:
        Policy constraint violation.

        May require adding a type attribute to the domain or type to satisfy the constraint.

        Constraints are defined in the policy sources in policy/constraints (general), policy/mcs (MCS), and policy/mls (MLS).
```

Comment: Did you write the system's _entire_ SELinux policy from scratch?

Comment: SELinux in Debian is just not operative.

Answer (score -1):

This link is explaining about constraint violation, and how to copw with:
http://cat.devtwo.org/post/An-SELinux-constraint-violation-(p-1-of-5)